# Apply different functions to columns of a dataframe selecting functions by name

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Let's say I've got a dataframe with multiple columns, some of which I want to transform. The column names define what transformation needs to be used.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = runif(n = 100, 0, 1), log10 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log2 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log1p = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), sqrt = runif(n = 100, 10, 100))
trans <- list()
trans$log10 <- log10
trans$log2 <- log2
trans$log1p <- log1p
trans$sqrt <- sqrt
```

Ideally, I would like to use an `across` call where the column names were matched up with the trans function names and the transformations would be performed on the fly.
The desired output is the following:

```
df_trans <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(log10 = trans$log10(log10),
                log2 = trans$log2(log2),
                log1p = trans$log1p(log1p),
                sqrt = trans$sqrt(sqrt))
df_trans
```

However, I don't want to manually specify each transformation separately. In the representative example I only have 4 but this number could vary and be significantly higher making manual specification cumbersome and error prone.

I have managed to match up the column names with the functions by turning the trans list into a data frame and left-joining but am then unable to call the function in the `trans_function` column.

```
trans_df <- enframe(trans, value = "trans_function")
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  left_join(trans_df) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(value = trans_function(value))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `value`.
> i `value = trans_function(value)`.
> x could not find function "trans_function"

I think I either need to find a way of calling the functions from the list columns or another way of matching up the function names with the column names. All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cur_column()` in `across` to get the column name and use it to subset `trans`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(names(trans), ~trans[[cur_column()]](.x))) %>%
  head

#  A         B    log10     log2    log1p     sqrt
#1 1 0.9148060 1.821920 6.486402 3.998918 3.470303
#2 2 0.9370754 1.470472 5.821200 3.932046 7.496103
#3 3 0.2861395 1.469690 6.437524 2.799395 8.171007
#4 4 0.8304476 1.653261 5.639570 3.700698 6.905755
#5 5 0.6417455 1.976905 4.597484 4.500461 9.441077
#6 6 0.5190959 1.985133 5.638341 4.551289 4.440590
```

Comparing it with output of `df_trans`.

```
head(df_trans)

#  A         B    log10     log2    log1p     sqrt
#1 1 0.9148060 1.821920 6.486402 3.998918 3.470303
#2 2 0.9370754 1.470472 5.821200 3.932046 7.496103
#3 3 0.2861395 1.469690 6.437524 2.799395 8.171007
#4 4 0.8304476 1.653261 5.639570 3.700698 6.905755
#5 5 0.6417455 1.976905 4.597484 4.500461 9.441077
#6 6 0.5190959 1.985133 5.638341 4.551289 4.440590
```

Answer (score 2):

One way can be to use lapply:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = runif(n = 100, 0, 1), log10 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log2 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log1p = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), sqrt = runif(n = 100, 10, 100))
trans <- list()
trans$log10 <- log10
trans$log2 <- log2
trans$log1p <- log1p
trans$sqrt <- sqrt


df_trans <- setNames(lapply(names(df),
            function(x) if(x %in% names(trans))
            { trans[[x]](df[,(x)])} else {df[,x]}),names(df)) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  as.data.frame() 

head(df_trans)
```

which gives:

```
  A         B    log10     log2    log1p     sqrt
  1 1 0.1365052 1.739051 6.301896 4.530600 4.318942
  2 2 0.1771364 1.549601 5.793220 4.521715 3.649834
  3 3 0.5195605 1.902438 4.819125 3.343266 6.788565
  4 4 0.8111208 1.572253 6.219991 4.075945 3.322401
  5 5 0.1153620 1.751276 6.306097 4.060292 7.817301
  6 6 0.8934218 1.724403 6.201123 3.235938 9.749128
```

The original dataframe being:

```
head(df)
  A         B    log10     log2    log1p     sqrt
  1 1 0.1365052 54.83409 78.89684 91.81428 18.65326
  2 2 0.1771364 35.44878 55.45401 90.99323 13.32129
  3 3 0.5195605 79.88006 28.22936 27.31143 46.08461
  4 4 0.8111208 37.34675 74.54249 57.90612 11.03835
  5 5 0.1153620 56.39961 79.12693 56.99123 61.11019
  6 6 0.8934218 53.01557 73.57393 24.43022 95.04549
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we may use `Map`

```
df[names(trans)] <- Map(function(x, y) x(y), trans, df[names(trans)])
```

-checking

```
> identical(df, df_trans)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = runif(n = 100, 0, 1), log10 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log2 = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), log1p = runif(n = 100, 10, 100), sqrt = runif(n = 100, 10, 100))

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-(A:B), ~ getFunction(cur_column())(.x))) %>% head

#>   A         B    log10     log2    log1p     sqrt
#> 1 1 0.9148060 1.821920 6.486402 3.998918 3.470303
#> 2 2 0.9370754 1.470472 5.821200 3.932046 7.496103
#> 3 3 0.2861395 1.469690 6.437524 2.799395 8.171007
#> 4 4 0.8304476 1.653261 5.639570 3.700698 6.905755
#> 5 5 0.6417455 1.976905 4.597484 4.500461 9.441077
#> 6 6 0.5190959 1.985133 5.638341 4.551289 4.440590
```